# Change CSS with jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change CSS property once sorted. Something likes this:

```
    $( "#sort" ).sortable({

        $(#div1).css("background-color","yellow");
    });
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you trying to style them to show which one was sorted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call initiate the plugin, make sure you pass a handler for the [stop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop):

```
$('#sort').sortable({
    stop: function(){
        $('#div1').css('background-color','yellow');
    }
});
```

Comment: This event is triggered __during__ sorting.

Comment: @Jacek_FH - True. Changed to stop(). Was going to suggest update() but it specifically says that it is fired "When the user stops sorting and the DOM positions have changed" which means if the user lets the sort finish on its own or the data is already sorted, nothing will happen.

Comment: I didn't use that because I fill that update is triggered after stop and after following DOM update. Thing to test anyways.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#events

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the events for sortable on the jQuery UI website: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events

Depending on the event you want, you can use:

```
$( "#sort" ).sortable({
    change: function(){
        $("#div1").css("background-color","yellow");
    }
});
```